# Mixing two column and one column in page with figures

Tags: graphics, captions, two-column, columns

I am writing a two column paper and I am struggling with forcing the layout of one specific page. This page should contain 4 figures, each with a caption, and a general paragraph discussing them. I would like to break from two columns to one column for the paragraph so that I would get something like:

[image: desired layout]

At the moment I am using:

```
\twocolumn[{
 \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\paragraph{Discussion}
yadiyada
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
}]
```

which gives me a two column page with the 4 figures, three on the left column and one on the right column; and a second one-column page with the discussion.

I have tried using `minipage` for the first time but with no success.

Comment: Short answer: Use [`multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) or use [`subcaption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) or indeed use two `minipage`s, each with two images with `\captionof`s. You could even use a `tabular` for the for images with captions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, if the following MWE gives what you like to obtain:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure*}[b]
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure A}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure B}
    \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-C}
\caption{Figure C}
    \label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Figure D}
    \label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Common caption}
\lipsum[11]
\end{figure*}
\lipsum*[2-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5fF]o.png

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot. It is not giving me the one column paragraph as I want yet but the 2x2 figure display is a big improvement.